# Inserting glyphs from an OTF font

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode

I'm trying to figure out how to insert specific pictographic glyphs from a font into my document.

So far I have managed to define a new font family using:

```
\newfontfamily\icons[
    Path = {"/Users/simontoth/Library/Fonts/"},
    Extension = .otf,
    UprightFont = *-Regular-400,
]{Font Awesome 6 Pro}
```

But when I try to use it with a Unicode glyph number, I run into an error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   f
l.11 {\icons \symbol{f1f9}
                          }
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of `\symbol` expects TeX's number syntax. Normally numbers should be given in decimal, but hexadecimal numbers can be used too by adding a `"` in front of them. In this case, TeX requires them to be given in uppercase. So you need e.g. `\symbol{"F1F9}` instead of `\symbol{f1f9}`.

Comment: OMG, thanks. I also needed the `"` prefix so `\symbol{"F1F9}`, but that works.

Comment: @ŠimonTóth Thanks, updated.